# Buscar y contar subcadenas (substring) de forma exacta en un rango

Tags: excel, vba

Esta es mi primera pregunta en esta página, espero que me puedan brindar su ayuda para resolver este pequeño problema.

**Contexto**: 
En un rango con determinadas dimensiones de tipo N x 1 (N filas por 1 columna), las celdas incluidas contienen texto. Dicho texto corresponde a nombres y apellidos. Tomar de referencia la siguiente columna como un caso simplificado:

JHON SOTOMAYOR
OSCAR SOTOMAYOR
JOEL SOTO
JOSÉ SOTO
MARIO SOTOMAYOR
MATEO SOTO
MARTÍN SOTOMAYOR
DAVID SOTO
ROMEO SOTO
TIRSO SOTOMAYOR

**Problema**: 
Buscar y contar las veces en las que el apellido SOTO y exclusivamente SOTO aparece en las celdas del rango. Posteriormente, almacenar el número de veces que aparece el apellido en una variable.

He intentado resolverlo por mi cuenta empleando la función **InStr** y la construcción **For each In**. Sin embargo, cuando coloco el apellido SOTO, el resultado de *counter* me sale 10 y no 5 como debería ser. ¿Cómo podría modificar mi código para que contabilice únicamente el apellido SOTO?

```VBA
    Dim _
    counter As Integer, _
    txt As String, _
    cell As Range, _
    arange As Range, _
    a1 As Range

    Set a1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Set arange = Range(a1, a1.End(xlDown))
    counter = 0

    txt = InputBox("Inserta el apellido que buscas.")

     For Each cell In arange
        If InStr(1, cell, txt, vbBinaryCompare) Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
     Next

    Debug.Print counter
```

Comment: InStr devuelve el primer caracter donde se encuentra la coincidencia, compara si ese valor es mayor que cero y el siguiente caracter de la cadena es espacio o no existe para determinar que solo se va a buscar esa palabra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido a SO en español. Suponiendo que tus datos siempre sean como los que has puesto, es decir, NOMBRE+ESPACIO+APELLIDO, entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente con Excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi fórmula en F2 es:

```
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$1:$A$10;"* "&D2)
```

Usamos la función CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO para contar cuántas celdas en el rango cumplen la condición definida.

> **[CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/contar-si-conjunto-funci%C3%B3n-contar-si-conjunto-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)**

El truco está en el criterio. Hemos usado un carácter comodín, el asterisco. Nuestro criterio es `"* "&D2`, es decir, `* APELLIDO`. Le estamos diciendo a Excel que cuente todas las celdas **que acaben en una palabra en concreto** (prececida de un espacio en blanco).

Si necesitas una solución en VBA, no te compliques y ve a lo fácil.

```
Sub test()
Dim MiApellido As String 'apellido que busco
Dim rng As Range 'rango de nombres y apellidos

MiApellido = InputBox("Introduzca apellido")

Set rng = Range("A1:A10") 'cambia al rango donde estén los datos

Debug.Print "Resultados para " & MiApellido & ": "; Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, "* " & MiApellido)
End Sub
```

Yo he probado este código con los valores `soto, sanchez, sotomayor` y mi ventana inmediato me da lo siguiente:

```
Resultados para soto:  5 
Resultados para sanchez:  0 
Resultados para sotomayor:  5
```

Espero que puedas adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

**IMPORTANTE:** Esto solamente funcionará siempre y cuando tus datos sean como en el ejemplo, es decir, NOMBRE+ESPACIO+APELLIDO. Si hay un patrón diferente, hay que adaptarlo.

Comment: Pero si el apellido soto es el primero y hay 2 apellidos, tampoco funcionará así. Sería más fácil hacer un `MiSplit = Split(String, " ")` y luego buscar dentro de `MiSplit`si existe `SOTO`.

Comment: @Damian, tu observación es correcta. Por eso puse una nota especificando *Esto solamente funcionará siempre y cuando tus datos sean como en el ejemplo, es decir, NOMBRE+ESPACIO+APELLIDO. Si hay un patrón diferente, hay que adaptarlo*

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que esta es la solución más sencilla, originalmente iba a utilizar arreglos (*arrays*) empleando la función **split** pero creo que esto es mucho mejor. Gracias.